# apt[-get] update does not work

Tags: apt

Ubuntu server 20.04

I have two identical systems with very similar configuration, the only difference is that one is connected to internet directly (it has 2 eth ports), I will refer to this system as #2.

#1 works fine

#2 apt or apt-get update fail all the time

```
Err:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Could not connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out
Could not connect to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
```

That's what I found out so far:

```
curl http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

The command above works fine (gives redirect [301] response with same url just adds '/' )

```
curl http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

This command does not work (no response from server)

Last command executed on #1 works fine

NB both systems run on ESXi VMs with 100% identical settings and again only difference is extra eth adapter on #2

NOTE: disabling iptables resolved the issue

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [22012:1990784]
:INPUT ACCEPT [18256:1795659]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [87:6148]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [6146:369688]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.2/32 -d 172.17.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8192 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.3/32 -d 172.17.0.3/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8191 -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8192 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:8192
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8191 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:8191
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Mar 21 01:24:50 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Mon Mar 21 01:24:50 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [36389:5136230]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1325:210810]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i ens160 -p udp -m udp --sport 67:68 --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ens160 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8192 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.3/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8191 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

Comment: Does #2 have a bunch of firewall rules in place via `iptables` That do not exist on #1? This is generally the issue that I find when people report this kid of problem and can be resolved via policy routing 

Comment: There is no much rules as this box is very simple output only service with docker container, except docker specific rules, only -j DROP applied to internet port
I don't know how rules would affect '/'?

Comment: All right , I reset iptables and apt update works... I wonder what rule is the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling iptables resolved the issue